# Oft bleibt nicht genügend Zeit, um alle Aufgaben gut überlegt bewältigen zu können

Tags: sentence-structure

> Oft bleibt nicht genügend Zeit, um alle Aufgaben gut überlegt bewältigen zu können

What is the function of "gut überlegt" in this context? Is it an adverb?

Comment: Ich darf nur darauf hinweisen, dass in deinem Beispielsatz das *können* überflüssig ist. Der Satz steht sauberer da, wenn du es einfach weglässt: *Oft bleibt nicht genügend Zeit, alle Aufgaben gut überlegt zu bewältigen.* Das *Können* ist überflüssig, weil es in der Satzaussage implizit enthalten ist.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I totally agree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's an **adverb**. *"gut überlegt"* refers to *"bewältigen"* (verb).

- To do something well thought out. (English)
- Etwas gut überlegt machen. (German)